# Iframe throw error: refused to frame because it violates the following content security policy directive

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-security-policy

I create a simple within my organization: `https://myserverapp`

The app is nodejs which serve the frontend:

```
const app = express();
app.use('/api/redirectme', cors(), (req, res) => {
  res.status(302).redirect('https://documents');
});
...
app.listen(...);
```

And `iframe` point to the api endpoint:

```
 <iframe src="https://myserverapp/api/redirectme" ...>
```

But I got error:

> refused to frame 'https://documents/' because it violates the
> following content security policy directive: "default-src 'self'".
> Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used
> as a fallback.

I add meta tag to index.html in order to solve this problem:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src https://documents/">
```

But the problem still exist with or without this meta tag.

What I need to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the existing CSP policy, which is probably set in the HTTP headers.

Trying to add an additional one with `<meta>` won't replace the existing rules.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have only one meta tag in index.html: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src https://documents/">`.  I have no existing meta in my index.html..

Comment: *Quentin* said that you already have published CSP through HTTP reponse header. NodeJS in dependencies have a [Helmet middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet-csp). Helmet 4 does publish a default CSP unlike Helmet 3. Two CSPs unite their rules via logical "AND", this is not what you expect.